# R code for sampling from a mixture of normal and exponential components

Tags: r, random, normal-distribution, gamma-distribution

I am trying to generate a bivariate sample from a mixture of two component distributions viz., normal and gamma distributions. I am using the 'copula' package for that.

The code I wrote is as follows-

```
library("copula")

mycop = normalCopula(param=c(0), dim=2, dispstr="ex")
mymvd = mvdc(
  copula=mycop, 
  margins=c("norm", "norm"),
  paramMargins=list(list(mean=-1, sd=0.5),list(mean=1, sd=0.5)))
```

This gave a bivariate sample from Normal(-1,1,0.5^2,0.5^2,0). The same code with exponential will lead give a bivariate sample from that distribution. But I don't know how to generate from w*BivariateNormal + (1-w)*BivariateGamma. Please help. I searched everywhere in yt but couldn't find anything. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you sample from a [mixture of two distributions](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Mixtures_of_Distributions) by:

- Generating a uniform(0, 1) variate (`runif` in R), then
- Sampling from the first distribution if that variate is less than `w`, or
- Sampling from the second distribution otherwise.

Similarly, you sample from a mixture of multiple distributions by generating a uniform, or non-uniform random integer, then sampling from a distribution depending on the integer chosen.

Comment: Suppose I want to sample from 0.3* Normal((0,0),diag(2,2)) + 0.7* Gamma(shape=(2,2), rate=(1,1)) where 0.3 and 0.7 are corresponding weights of the marginals. Can you please kindly explain what to do after generating a sample from Unif(0,1)?

Comment: In your example, compare the uniform variate `U` with 0.3.  If `U` is less than 0.3, sample from `Normal(...)`.  Otherwise, sample `Gamma(...)`.  In this way, you sample from `Normal(...)` with probability 3/10, and from `Gamma(...)` with probability 7/10.